# AngularJS ng-change event for select not firing after jQuery UI Selectmenu

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have the following part of VIEW code:

```
<select class="my_select_class" id="my_select_id" name="my_select_name" ng-model="my_select_model" ng-change="my_func()">
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
</select>
```

Also i have my function

```
    $scope.my_func() = function () {
        console.log('Fire!');
};
```

While everything is OK. Event is triggered.

But when i bind my `select` with **jQuery UI Selectmenu:**

```
$('.my_select_class').selectmenu({ style: 'new_style' });
```

after that event `ng-change` no more fires.

How do you think is this behavior is connected with `display: none` style after `selecmenu` is applied?

Comment: Have you tried using [Angular UI-Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) instead?

Comment: can you set up plunk to reproduce bug?

Comment: did you wrap ui select menu onto directive?

Comment: no i didn't. if it is possible please give me example of using directive with ui select menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.selectmenu()` method, the original `<select>` is hidden (`display:none`) and a brand new tree with `<ul>` and `<li>` is generated.

For example on the *JQuery UI* demo page for [SelectMenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/), you can activate your browser's developper toolbox and then see this underlying source :

**1: the original <SELECT>, now hidden**

```
<select name="speed" id="speed" style="display: none;">
    <option>Slower</option>
    <option>Slow</option>
    <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
    <option>Fast</option>
    <option>Faster</option>
</select>
```

**2: the code generated by JQuery UI**

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front" style="top: 78.5px; left: 17.5px;">
    <ul aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="speed-button" id="speed-menu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-1" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 198px;">
      <li class="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option">Slower</li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option">Slow</li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option">Medium</li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option">Fast</li>
      <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="option">Faster</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Therefore all attached directives like `ng-model`, `ng-change` are attached to a no-longer used DOM element.
It seems that AngularJS couldn't work in that conditions.

Best regards,